# div needs to be centered horizontally and fully occupy vertical space

Tags: html, css

I have something akin to the following structure:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the inner div to occupy the full vertical height of the page except for an 8px margin from top and bottom.  I also want this div to be centered horizontally within the body with a minimum margin of 8px from left and right.  I do not want the page to scroll and need to avoid using calc() at all costs for browser support-ability.

I have tried:

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}
div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    bottom: 8px;
}
```

Which is fine for forcing it to leave an 8px "margin", but centering it horizontally now becomes impossible without using a calc() since its width is variable and there are no elements for it to be relative to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understand your question right... you want the `div` to fill the whole window, except for 8px... Is that right?

You can do that using this CSS:

```
div {
    background: lightblue;
    position: absolute;
    top: 8px;
    left: 8px;
    bottom: 8px;
    right: 8px;
}
```

Check the [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MySPp/1/).

**[OPTION 2]**

If you want the div to have a fixed width (or semi-fixed with `max-width` or `min-width`) you can use this code:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    padding: 8px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;    
}
div {
    background: lightblue;
    width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 100%;
}
```

It says the body to be 100% height and width and calculate the padding within it's width (therefor the `box-sizing`) property. Then you can specify the width on the div, and center it by using `margin: 0 auto`.

Check the [**updated demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MySPp/2/).

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/5X79H/1/

following code will center your div:

```
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="center"></div>
</div>

</body>
```

style:

```
.center {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color:maroon; 
    width:100px; 
    height: 100px;
}
.container{
       width:100%;
    text-align: center;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use margin:

```
div {
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
div{
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

centered div

**UPDATE:** remove position: absolute;
[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Shashi0812/L4gbz/1/)

Comment: the problem with this is that it will be perfectly centered, but it needs to occupy the entire vertical space available (except for 8px from top and bottom)

Answer (score 0):

I think it's best to introduce a new div:

```
<body>

<div class="container">
  <div class="center"></div>
</div>

</body>
```

Then in your CSS you could do this:

```
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  bottom: 8px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.center {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```